# Unable to access gitlab repository in docker

Tags: git, docker, gitlab

I've runned [gitlab container](https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/) and created new repo. When I try to clone that repo using http or ssh, I receive:

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://root@3908eec185ce/root/my-awesome-project.git/': Could not resolve host: 3908eec185ce
```

there is how I clone:

```
git clone http://root@3908eec185ce/root/my-awesome-project.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution. instead of

```
http://root@3908eec185ce/root/my-awesome-project.git/
```

I use

```
http://root@[host]:[port]/root/my-awesome-project.git/
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't quite have GitLab configured correctly. The `external_url` in the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file should exactly match the name you will use to clone/push/pull, and access the web UI.